# Create separate primary partition to install linux

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

[image]

I tried GParted live to extend and create primary partition but it is taking a lot of time. When will the process get finished? Also, whenever I tried to dual boot Linux. windows partition is shown with other small primary partition but other partition is shown as single. I don't want to loose data.

Comment: Could you add more details about your partition table (e.g. an image)?

Comment: I have embed link of the screenshot. Do review it. The main problem is I was unable to install any linux distro creating seperate partition without loss of data. Any pro geek .. HELP????????????????????????????????????????????//

Comment: Ubuntu will probably be installed on the big grey free space (`/dev/sda4`). You can resize it.

Comment: The sd4 partition include multiple partition in windows but linux show a single partiton , Do you know how. How much time does it take to resize the partition. I waited 2 hr to resize but the task never get competed ..

Comment: **You have errors on your partitions** (the red exclamation marks): do a full system back-up, correct the errors (using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) and *only then try modifying your partitions!*

Answer (score 0):

The small partition before Windows partition is probably needed to boot your windows partition and you mustn't touch it.

You can try to follow these steps to install Ubuntu:

1. Move the content of `/dev/sda4` (1.39GiB) in a secure place (like Windows partition or an external USB);
2. Now reboot your PC from Ubuntu live drive (DVD or USB) and delete `/dev/sda4` partition: select the partition, *right-click* on it and choose *delete*;
3. *right-click* on the `unallocated` space (grey box) and choose *new*. Now select the wished partition size, format it as `ext4` and be sure to make it as *primary partition*.
   **Note**: keep a small `unallocated` space as big as your RAM. This is needed for [swap area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).
4. Once you have created a *primary partition* repeat the previous step
   and create swap area choosing `linux-swap` instead of `ext4` as file system.
5. Apply the changes and wait for the end of work.
6. When you are ready, start Ubuntu installation and when you reach section *Installation type* choose *Something Else*.
7. You should see a similar screen as `GParted`. *Right-click* on `ext4` partition and select *Ext4 journaling file system* instead *Do not use partition* and select as mount point `/`. After this do the same for swap partition and select *Swap area* instead *Do not use partition*.
   In the end, choose `/dev/sda` drive (default) to install `GRUB` bootloader. When you go ahead with installation check that it will use the correct partitions.

Following these steps you should be able to install Ubuntu.

**Edit partition through Windows**

If you can't edit your partition in Ubuntu, you can try to do this in Windows. So *right-click* on `This PC` and choose `Manage`. Now from the list on the left select `Disk managent`. After this you should see something like `GParted` (similar image [here](http://www.disk-partition.com/resource/images/disk-management-windows7/windows7-disk-managment.gif)). Then select the 387GB partition, *right-click* and choose `Delete volume`. Now you can come back to Ubuntu and you should be able to edit that partition as you want.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Do review the warnign sign in partition. I was unable to play with any partition..